# What's the right way to implement equality in ruby

Tags: ruby, equality

For a simple struct-like class:

```
class Tiger
  attr_accessor :name, :num_stripes
end
```

what is the correct way to implement equality correctly, to ensure that `==`, `===`, `eql?`, etc work, and so that instances of the class play nicely in sets, hashes, etc.

**EDIT**

Also, what's a nice way to implement equality when you want to compare based on state that's not exposed outside the class? For example:

```
class Lady
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(age)
    @age = age
  end
end
```

here I'd like my equality method to take @age into account, but the Lady doesn't expose her age to clients. Would I have to use instance_variable_get in this situation?

Comment: [This is a nice writeup comparing the ins and outs of defining object equality](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/ruby-equality-and-object-comparison/)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To simplify comparison operators for objects with more than one state variable, create a method that returns all of the object's state as an array.  Then just compare the two states:

```
class Thing

  def initialize(a, b, c)
    @a = a
    @b = b
    @c = c
  end

  def ==(o)
    o.class == self.class && o.state == state
  end

  protected

  def state
    [@a, @b, @c]
  end

end

p Thing.new(1, 2, 3) == Thing.new(1, 2, 3)    # => true
p Thing.new(1, 2, 3) == Thing.new(1, 2, 4)    # => false
```

Also, if you want instances of your class to be usable as a hash key, then add:

```
  alias_method :eql?, :==

  def hash
    state.hash
  end
```

These need to be public.

Comment: I really like this trick of comparing objects using by delegating comparison to the state array.

Comment: unfortunately, this was over my head

Comment: @kraftydevil That is indeed unfortunate.  I'm sorry about that.

Comment: What about class comparison like this: `o.is_a?(self.class)`?. I know, how it behaves (descendants), but I am searching for best practice.

Comment: @DonPaulie I don't know if there's a best practice there.  I don't use inheritance much, so I haven't had to decide whether an instance of a subclass should be equal to an instance of its parent class. I'd take that on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 24):

To test all your instance variables equality at once:

```
def ==(other)
  other.class == self.class && other.state == self.state
end

def state
  self.instance_variables.map { |variable| self.instance_variable_get variable }
end
```

Comment: This really is way better because it goes a long way to ensure that you're not accidentally leaving out any variables. Now, there may also be some unintended consequences of automatically using every instance variable, but I'm not sure and won't know until it surprises me one day.

Comment: It's true, you can add optional parameters, like 'only' or 'except' for those particular cases.

Comment: I would caution against that. Quite often you have specific identifying attributes which might even be a very small subset of all the attributes, e.g. a book usually has an ISBN number.
Nothing against this answer, just cautionary tale on the "this really is way better" comment.

Answer (score 1):

Usually with the `==` operator.

```
def == (other)
  if other.class == self.class
    @name == other.name && @num_stripes == other.num_stripes
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. However I think that if you only define == then instances of the class won't behave as expected in hashes and sets.

Comment: Also, I /think/ that == isn't supposed to check type equality (as your example is doing). That's what eql? is supposed to do. Could be wrong on that tho.

Comment: The behavior only varies if you make it vary, Pete. Last I checked `true == true` (and `1+1 == 2`) still returns `true`...