# What methods gets called when I try to compare custom object with string?

Tags: ruby

I have some object that I'd like to compare with string. I'd like to know what method should I implement in order conversion of my object happens automatically when used as an argument to comparison operator.

For example:

```
line == '2 hello world'
```

at the left my object and I'd like to compare it with some string. Currently, I've implemented **to_s** on my object, but nevertheless I get false even if contained string is equal to which I'm comparing with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the right way to implement equality in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931604/whats-the-right-way-to-implement-equality-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override your class' [`==` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F).

```
class MyClass
  def ==(other)
    # custom equal comparison logic here
    # if you just need string comparison
    to_s == other
  end
end
```