# Undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I have an undefined method.

```
rb:31:in `add_song': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I do understand that `@library[artist]` gives `nil`, but I don't understand why and do not know how to fix it. Any advice?

```
module Promptable
  def prompt(message = "What music would you like to add", symbol = ":>")
  print message
  print symbol
  gets.chomp
  end
end


class Library
  attr_accessor :artist, :song
  def initialize
    @library = {}
  end

  def add_artist(artist)
    @library[artist] = []
  end

  def add_song(song)
    @library[artist] << song
  end

  def show
    puts @library
  end
end

class Artist
  attr_accessor :name, :song

  def initialize(artist)
    @name = artist[:name]
    @song = artist[:song]
  end

  def to_s
   "#{name}, #{song}"
  end
end


if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  include Promptable
  include Menu
  my_library = Library.new
  my_library.add_artist(Artist.new(:name => prompt("What it the artist name    ?")))
  my_library.add_song(Artist.new(:song => prompt("What is the song name ?")))
  my_library.show
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `add_artist` with one instance of `Artist` and `add_song` with another. When you look up the artist's list of songs in `add_song` with `@library[artist]` you're using a hash key (the second instance of `Artist`) which is not equivalent to the hash key under which you stored the list (the first instance of `Artist`), so you're not getting the list back, but `nil`.

To use two different instances of `Artist` as equivalent hash keys, you'll need to decide when two instances of `Artist` should be equal and [implement `eql?` and `hash` appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931604/whats-the-right-way-to-implement-equality-in-ruby).